# Merging two arraylists without creating third one

Tags: arrays, list, merge

Here is one task, i was trying to solve. You must write the function

```
void merge(ArrayList a, ArrayList b)  {
// code
}
```

The function recieves two ArrayLists with equal size as input parameters [a1, a2, ..., an], [b1, b2, ..., bn]. **The execution result is the 1st ArrayList must contain elements of both lists, and they alternate consistently ([a1, b1, a2, b2, ..., an, bn])** Please read the bold text twice =)

Code must work as efficiently as possible.

Here is my solution

```
public static void merge(ArrayList a, ArrayList b) {
ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
int i = 0;

Iterator iter1 = a.iterator();
Iterator iter2 = b.iterator();
while ((iter1.hasNext() || iter2.hasNext()) && i < (a.size() + b.size())) {
    if (i % 2 ==0) {
        result.add(iter1.next());
    } else {
        result.add(iter2.next());
    }
    i++;
}

a = result;
```

}

I know it's not perfect at all. But I can't understand how to merge in the 1st list without creating tmp list.

Thanks in advance for taking part.

Comment: You haven't asked us a question. "Here is my assignment; do it for me" doesn't count.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write a method that merges two array lists, alternating elements from both array lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16165942/write-a-method-that-merges-two-array-lists-alternating-elements-from-both-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double ArrayList `a`'s size. Set last two elements of `a` to the last element of the old `a` and the last element of `b`. Keep going, backing up each time, until you reach the beginnings of `a` and `b`. You have to do it from the rear because otherwise you will write over the original `a`'s values.

Comment: Thanks, John ! Solution is so simple ! As always.

Answer (score 0):

In the end i got this:

```
public static void merge(ArrayList<Integer> arr1, ArrayList<Integer> arr2) {
        int indexForArr1 = arr1.size() - 1;
        int oldSize = arr1.size();
        int newSize = arr1.size() + arr2.size();

        /*
            decided not to create new arraylist with new size but just to fill up old one with nulls
         */
        fillWithNulls(arr1, newSize);

        for(int i = (newSize-1); i >= 0; i--) {
            if (i%2 != 0) {
                int indexForArr2 = i%oldSize;
                arr1.set(i,arr2.get(indexForArr2));
                oldSize--; // we reduce the size because we don't need tha last element any more
            } else {
                arr1.set(i, arr1.get(indexForArr1));
                indexForArr1--;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void fillWithNulls(ArrayList<Integer> array, int newSize) {
        int delta = newSize - array.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < delta; i++) {
            array.add(null);
        }
    }
```

Thanks John again for bright idea!

Comment: It'd be a little more efficient to use `oldSize - 1` in your `for` loop and set elements `i * 2` and `i * 2 + 1` of `arr1` in each iteration. You'd get rid of the two `%`s and the `if` that way. And use `ArrayList.ensureCapacity` to efficiently allocate memory for the larger `arr1`.

Comment: i'll try to replace oldsize var later
ArrayList.ensureCapacity is obvious, again)

Comment: Only now I remembered about put(index, object) method in List collection