# Two array lists

Tags: arrays

Write a method

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> merge(ArrayList<Integer> a, ArrayList<Integer> b)
```

that merges two array lists, alternating elements from both array lists. If one array
list is shorter than the other, then alternate as long as you can and then append the
remaining elements from the longer array list. For example, 
if a is

```
1 4 9 16
```

and b is

```
9 7 4 9 11
```

then merge returns the array list

```
1 9 4 7 9 4 16 9 11
```

Comment: So what's your problem?

Comment: I need the merge list.
merge returns the array list 1 9 4 7 9 4 16 9 11 
merge of a and b

Comment: So, what is incorrect?

Comment: Duplicated! Exactly the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16165942/write-a-method-that-merges-two-array-lists-alternating-elements-from-both-array

Comment: There are a lot of answers ready for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> merge(ArrayList<Integer> x,
        ArrayList<Integer> y) {
    ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>(x.size() + y.size());
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < x.size() && j < y.size(); i++, j++) {
        temp.add(x.get(i));
        temp.add(y.get(j));
    }
    while (i < x.size()) {
        temp.add(x.get(i));
        i++;
    }
    while (j < y.size()) {
        temp.add(y.get(j));
        j++;
    }
    return temp;

}
```

`Merged is [1, 9, 4, 7, 9, 4, 16, 9, 25, 11, 36, 21, 49, 64, 81]`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> merge(ArrayList<Integer> x, ArrayList<Integer> y)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>(x.size() + y.size());      
    int m  = x.size() > y.size() ? x.size() : y.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        if (i < x.size()) temp.add(x.get(i));
        if (i < y.size()) temp.add(y.get(i));
    }

    return temp;
}
```

Output:

```
Merged is [1, 9, 4, 7, 9, 4, 16, 9, 25, 11, 36, 21, 49, 64, 81]
```